# jQuery (coffeescript) dynamic links

Tags: jquery, dynamic, coffeescript, bind, unbind

To be short and precise:

I have a link, clicking which a new div is inserted into the list. 
Each div contains a link to delete this div.

So, in the middle of working, it looks like this:

```
<div id="list">
   <div id="item"><a href="#" id="remove_item">Remove</a></div>
   <div id="item"><a href="#" id="remove_item">Remove</a></div>
</div>
```

As for the click handler I have

```
$("#remove_item").live 'click', (e) ->
    $(this).parent().remove()
    $(this).die()  # Unbind
```

Now, my problem here is in odd behaviour of this handler. If I click on the link of the very last inserted DIV it is being removed properly, but if I click on the very first one - apart from it being removed, it also removes every single one of them, that happen to be standing **after** it. So clicking the first one, will, basically, remove everything.

And I need to remove only the current one, obviously! :)

And I don't have a clue, why unbinding is not working. I don't know if it is related to multiple firing or not. :(

Can someone help me with this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I don't know what the problem was, but after I had rearranged some of the HTML layout, the problem was solved. And I still don't quite understand the reason. Ah well, whatever. Thanks for all of you guys, who tried to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but not enough points yet.

First of all, consider using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) as .live() is deprecated.

I can't reproduce your problem, your piece of code works for me here, probably something wrong with multiple binding and unbinding, as you mention. Maybe a little bit more of code would help.

Furthermore, you shouldn't use the same id. IDs should be unique for each element, better have a `class="remove_item"` and a unique id for each div.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing .live to .on, and .die to .off didn't help, unfortunately. I'll provide additional code very soon. By the way, could you show my code working via jsfiddle or something :)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbDZF/).I converted your code to javascript from js2coffee.org

Comment: Ah. That won't do, becase in your example content is static! And I have all there items inserted dynamically. I'll prepare jsfiddle example soon.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of a DOM element needs to be unique.

You most likely just need to change this:

```
<div id="list">
   <div id="item"><a href="#" id="remove_item">Remove</a></div>
   <div id="item"><a href="#" id="remove_item">Remove</a></div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="list">
   <div class="item"><a href="#" class="remove_item">Remove</a></div>
   <div class="item"><a href="#" class="remove_item">Remove</a></div>
</div>
```

With the related CoffeeScript changed to:

```
$(".remove_item").live 'click', (e) ->
    $(this).parent().remove()
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you don't need to call `$(this).die()` since you still want the other DIVs to be deletable.

Comment: I've tried to do like this (id -> class), but It doesn't help. It keeps removing all the "items" standing after the deletable one.